# Comparing tuple values

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm quite new to Python/Flask and am writing a little script for some home automation I'm playing with.

At the moment, there's a route in my script that gets run by a cron job.  This sniffs for bluetooth packets to see who's in and who's out of the house so I can control the heating.  There's a row in my table for each person and a status which is either In or Out.

This works perfectly.

I've got another route to read the values back and display either a green or red bar on my dashboard depending on if they're in or out.

It's reading the values and doing some logic that I'm having problems with.

If I get the status for a person and display it on my dashboard (created with an HTML template), the value it displays is:

('In',)

In the MySQL table it's just In - no quotes or parentheses.

In my Python script I have:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user = "*****", passwd = "*****", db = "mydb")
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("select status from occupants WHERE id = '1'")
                data = cursor.fetchone()
                result = data
                #result = str(result)
                if (result == "In"):
                   result = "In"
                else:
                  result = "Out"
```

This always returns Out.

I've tried various things in my if statement but I obviously haven't hit the right one.  I've even tried:

```
if (result == "('In',)")
```

But even this returns Out.

Starting to tear my hair out now as I've been searching and playing for about 2 days just on this.

Any ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as always, 5 minutes after posting, I try something different and get it working.  However, I'm not sure if this is a fudge or if it's a valid thing to do:

```
if 'In' in result:
```

This now works.

For the purposes of this exercise, it doesn't really matter if it's a dirty workround but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant/conventional solution just for my learning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value by index. 
Python returns tuples for the rows.You need to get the first column.

Just get the value by index, data[0]

Then you go on with comparison.

Edit: when you use the "in" operators, you are just looping through the tuple.

It works buts not a good idea, when you already know for sure, the data you are looking for is at index 0.

Comment: I had that originally and changed my query to fetchone instead of fetchall.  In both cases, even without the index, it still read the correct value from the table.  Thank you for your help, though.  For the moment, I'll probably stick with "in".

Comment: You should always try to write optimized code, it will help you in long run. Just my advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `cursor.fetchone()`, which returns a  `tuple` or `None`(if element not found). So what you are receiving after executing the command is a tuple with only one element, which makes lesser sense in this context, but that is how this Python API returns data. So even after using `fetchone()` you need to access the first element explicitly, which can be done as `lst[0]`. So you need to change the line as:

```
result = ""
if data is not None: 
    result = data[0]
print result
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give that a try a bit later.  It's doing what I need for the moment and I'm impatient to get to grips with the API for the thermostat to turn the heating off if the house is empty :)

Answer (score 1):

You have more Data in "result" then just "In". For example:

```
a = ["yes", "hello"]
b = "no"

if "yes" == a:
    print("yes yes yes")
else:
    print("Something is wrong")
```

This gives you "Something is wrong" as output, but if you do:

```
a = ["yes", "hello"]
b = "no"

if "yes" in a:
    print("yes yes yes")
else:
    print("Something is wrong")
```

Now you get "yes yes yes" as output. Hope this helps a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Abhijith; indexing would be a better idea.

It's likely the result of you database query should look like this:

```
database_query_result = [('In',)]
```

If that's the case, you could just grab the occupants status like the below to get the answer you desire without a logical comparison.

```
result = database_query_result[0][0]
print(result)
```

Why this works:

- database_query_result[0] gives you the tuple -> ('In', )
- database_query_result[0][0] gives you the tuple's value. -> 'In'

Comment: Thank you.  That's an interesting one but makes sense to me with the tiny, tiny bit of work I've done trying to extract values from JSON.